# Broadcast receiver not working for incoming call detections

Tags: android, broadcast, receiver

This is the code Ive implemented, by the way Ive read all other question on stackoverflow regarding this topic but it still doesnt work

PhoneCallReceiver class

```
import java.util.Date;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;

public abstract class PhonecallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

//The receiver will be recreated whenever android feels like it.  We need a static variable to remember data between instantiations

private static int lastState = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;
private static Date callStartTime;
private static boolean isIncoming;
private static String savedNumber;  //because the passed incoming is only valid in ringing


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    //We listen to two intents.  The new outgoing call only tells us of an outgoing call.  We use it to get the number.
    if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL")) {
        savedNumber = intent.getExtras().getString("android.intent.extra.PHONE_NUMBER");
    }
    else{
        String stateStr = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
        String number = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
        int state = 0;
        if(stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)){
            state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;
        }
        else if(stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)){
            state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK;
        }
        else if(stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)){
            state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING;
        }


        onCallStateChanged(context, state, number);
    }
}

//Derived classes should override these to respond to specific events of interest
protected void onIncomingCallStarted(Context ctx, String number, Date start){}
protected void onOutgoingCallStarted(Context ctx, String number, Date start){}
protected void onIncomingCallEnded(Context ctx, String number, Date start, Date end){}
protected void onOutgoingCallEnded(Context ctx, String number, Date start, Date end){}
protected void onMissedCall(Context ctx, String number, Date start){}

//Deals with actual events

//Incoming call-  goes from IDLE to RINGING when it rings, to OFFHOOK when it's answered, to IDLE when its hung up
//Outgoing call-  goes from IDLE to OFFHOOK when it dials out, to IDLE when hung up
public void onCallStateChanged(Context context, int state, String number) {
    if(lastState == state){
        //No change, debounce extras
        return;
    }
    switch (state) {
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
            isIncoming = true;
            callStartTime = new Date();
            savedNumber = number;
            onIncomingCallStarted(context, number, callStartTime);
            break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
            //Transition of ringing->offhook are pickups of incoming calls.  Nothing done on them
            if(lastState != TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING){
                isIncoming = false;
                callStartTime = new Date();
                onOutgoingCallStarted(context, savedNumber, callStartTime);
            }
            break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
            //Went to idle-  this is the end of a call.  What type depends on previous state(s)
            if(lastState == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING){
                //Ring but no pickup-  a miss
                onMissedCall(context, savedNumber, callStartTime);
            }
            else if(isIncoming){
                onIncomingCallEnded(context, savedNumber, callStartTime, new Date());
            }
            else{
                onOutgoingCallEnded(context, savedNumber, callStartTime, new Date());
            }
            break;
    }
    lastState = state;
}
```

}

I also add this class which extends the last one:

```
public class CallReceiver extends PhonecallReceiver {

    @Override
    protected void onIncomingCallStarted(Context ctx, String number, Date start) {
      //here is what I want to perform some tasks
    }

    @Override
    protected void onOutgoingCallStarted(Context ctx, String number, Date start) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onIncomingCallEnded(Context ctx, String number, Date start, Date end) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onOutgoingCallEnded(Context ctx, String number, Date start, Date end) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onMissedCall(Context ctx, String number, Date start) {

    }

}
```

But it doesnt mater what I put on that, the code never does anything. 
I means the method  protected void onIncomingCallStarted(Context ctx, String number, Date start) never runs

The manifest is:

```
<receiver android:name=".MainActivity$CallReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>    </application>
```

and the permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS" />
```

Please note that the class CallReceiver is create in MainActivity class.
What Im doing wrong? I cant fix it. please help

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these 2 permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/>
```

Comment: Thanks. I could fix it, setting the permission from code and not from manifest. (Looks like the user must see the alert message that app would manage phone calls). But I cant do anything from the broadcast receiver, just shows a toast message Why that?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I wrote that originally and ought to update it-  as of newer versions of Android, you can no longer register a receiver to that signal in the manifest-  you can only do it programmatically.  Which means you'll need a foreground service to run and register the receiver.

Looks like that change was in Android O.

Comment: Thanks. I could fix it, setting the permission from code and not from manifest. (Looks like the user must see the alert message that app would manage phone calls). But I cant do anything from the broadcast receiver, just shows a toast message Why that?